# Create NSArray From Objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have `NSMutableArray` with 10,000 objects,  each object has Name, Details, ...etc.
I want to Create an `NSArray` Which contains ONLY the Names of all objects.

Answer (score 7):

Use KVC

```
NSArray *names = [myArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Check the docs for [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

> **valueForKey:**
>   Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.